# Cannot use shrines after destroying Adanos artifacts

Tags: gothic-3

I have a problem. I chose to destroy Adanos artifacts. After that, I cannot use shrines, so I cannot learn Beliar spells AND cannot grow my lives. Now I'm in a position where I need more lives but I don't know how. Is there a possibility to learn lives and Beliar spells somewhere else? Or am I simply done?

Comment: The game is close to be over after destroying the artifacts? What do you need live and spells for? If you want to level your Character up you have to do this earlier

Comment: well yes. Its close to over. But i dont have enough rep with hashashins so i cannot get to zuben (and kill him) and also i need to kill king which require a lot of hp because everybody in castle instantly attack me and well, fighting system is REALLY bad designed.I have like 200 skill points but i cannot level up anything usefull for this last annoying part! In the end i activated god mod because game have SO BAD fighting. Its slow, not responsive, with delay, hero after hit walk one step forward. So i killed them, finish last quest and uninstall and never come back. I love gothic but this...